# How do you handle navigation in a token-secured web application?

Tags: node.js, http, token, passport.js

I have a rather conceptual question, I'm sure it's fairly stupid, but I can't figure it out.
So I am building a simple node.js app to learn, I want to make a web app which is has a set of REST web APIs for everything (including authentication), and then the presentation.
For authentication I am using token-based auth with PassportJS.
So when a user wants to access the site, he'll obtain a token from the authentication API, in turn he'll need to pass this token in a HTTP Header on each request to the app.

My question is, how is this handled in the code? When the app gets the token (for example from a login page which hits the auth API), should it attempt to store it in the local machine (for example LocalStorage, or Cookie) and then on each new page fetch it and use it in a Header? Should each page's javascript attempt to load the token from the local storage automatically? I tried looking for an example, but haven't found a complete one that deals with how you handle navigation when you're depending on sending a header on every single request (that you want authenticated).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is authenticated return a secure session cookie which will be stored by the user's browser. Now on every request, this cookie will be sent by the browser to your application automatically, which you can check in your backend code (typically controller) to verify the existence of user session.